# How do I get RMS Express to work in Wine/Ubuntu14.04

Tags: wine

RMS Express is a free application from Winlink 2000 used in ham radio.  It runs in XP and up.  I have installed it under Wine 1.7 but components of the application do not run.  Research shows it relies on .NET 2.0.  I have installed various .NET versions using winetricks.  That has not helped.  An interesting side affect of that is that Wine will no longer install from the MSI once a dot net has been installed.  Or at least I can not get it to install.  Into and about to wipe my 7th wine build.  It starts under mono and parts of it function but other parts do not.  However once a dot net version has been installed nothing works.

That's what I know at this point.  Suggestions?  Requests for error listings will be honored but it will take a bit of time.

Comment: See, sometimes you can't just "get something to work" with Wine. Sometimes if it doesn't run it doesn't. Period. Before trying to install and run anything with Wine you should search in their Apllication Database, which tells you if programs install/run/work under Wine. http://appdb.winehq.org

Comment: Did you install wine-mono?

Comment: Anything can run under wine, it just needs a bit of hack.  The fact that it does not run on first install just means the dependencies have not been met.  Of course sometimes it's just easier to port the app to Linux and be done with it.

Angel asked:  Did you install Wine Mono?
Yes I did, and that did not work.

I need to go back and document each step I have taken up to this point.  But do keep the suggestions coming.

Prepitious

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work on Mint 17, which is based on Ubuntu 14.

Used Wine 1.8, set the arch to 32bit and the Windows version to Win 7
Use a newer winetricks to set the sound to ALSA
Then you have to set up links to com ports and edit the registry

http://dcj21.net/how-tos/install-rms-express-linux